# Inheritance of template class defined by inner class gives error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, inner-classes, cyclic-dependency

This code gives error
the code:

```
class B;

template <typename T>
class C {
public:
    T cx;
};

class A : public C<A::B> {
public:
    class B { };
};
```

the error:
Error   C2079   'C::cx' uses undefined class 'B'

As you can see i tried cyclic depentencies to no avail
Any ideas?

Comment: The error message says it. `class B;` is a declaration, not a definition. If you `class B{};`, then it will compile.

Comment: wow thanks, would have never guessed myself